# VBA: Outlook Exchange "Global Address List" has no Entries while "Offline Global Address List" has

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to access the Global Address List (GAL) of an Exchange Server via Excel VBA macro. I can find the list, but it has no entries.
Other lists, e.g. the "Offline Global Address List" do have entries.
I've made sure the list has entries.

I'm accessing the list as follows:

```
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outNms As Outlook.Namespace

Set outApp = New Outlook.Application
Set outNms = outAppStd.GetNamespace("MAPI")
outNms.Logon ("Outlook")

' Im on German localization. The entry exists, but is empty/has a .Count of -1
outNmsStd.AddressLists("Globale Addressliste").AddressEntries

' This does have entries:
outNmsStd.AddressLists("Offline Global Address List").AddressEntries
```

I noticed that the "Offline Global Address List" is of `OlAddressListType: olExchangeGlobalAddressList`, while the "Globale Addressliste" is `OlAddressListType: olExchangeContainer`, but I could not gain anything useful from that.

My admin team also provided me the attached screenshot, but I'm not sure of that's the address list I'm looking for:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior if Outlook is offline. Try to make sure offline address book is downloaded in Outlook (Send/Receive | Send/Receive Groups | Download Address Book) and check to see if you can browse GAL address lists while offline. Also note that Distribution List members cannot be accessed at all in the offline mode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My Outlook is not offline though. I can download the GAL to the offline list, but I'd prefer to not have my users do that every time in order to have the most recent data.